# my node.js code sometimes work, sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, telegram-bot, telegraf

I develop a telegram bot by node js and telegraf.
When a group member add a member in group, this code execute

```
bot.on('new_chat_members', (ctx) => {
    if(ctx.message.new_chat_members[0]['is_bot'] == false){
        Add.insertForcedAddUsersList(ctx.message.chat.id, ctx.message.from.id, ctx.message.from.first_name, ctx.message.from.last_name, ctx.message.new_chat_members[0]['id']);
    }
});
```

And then this function works:

```
var insertForcedAddUsersList = (chatId, userId, firstName, lastName, addedUserId) => {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM forced_add_users_list WHERE chat_id="+chatId+" AND user_id="+userId;
    Model.pool.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            if(result[0]){
                var addedUsersIdArray = result[0]['added_users_id'].split('|');
                var repetitiveUserFlag = false;
                for(var i=0;i<addedUsersIdArray.length;i++){
                    if(addedUsersIdArray[i] == addedUserId){
                        repetitiveUserFlag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(repetitiveUserFlag == false){
                    sql = "UPDATE forced_add_users_list SET first_name="+"'"+firstName+"',last_name='"+lastName+"',added_number='"+(parseInt(result[0]['added_number'],10)+1)+"',added_users_id='"+result[0]['added_users_id']+"|"+addedUserId+"' WHERE chat_id="+chatId+" AND user_id="+userId;
                    Model.pool.query(sql, function (err, result2) {
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err);
                        else
                            canSendMessage(chatId, userId, firstName, lastName, parseInt(result[0]['added_number'],10)+1);
                    });
                }
            }else{
                sql = "INSERT INTO forced_add_users_list(chat_id, user_id, first_name, last_name, added_number, added_users_id) VALUES(" + chatId + ",'" + userId +  "','" + firstName + "','" + lastName + "','1','" + addedUserId + "')";
                Model.pool.query(sql, function (err, result2) {
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err);
                    else
                        canSendMessage(chatId, userId, firstName, lastName, 1);
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The problem is when i add 3 or more members to group at the same time, sometimes the first one and the last one added to database and sometimes all of them added. 
Also sometimes the INSERT SQL command works twice instead one time.
What's the problem. I'm new in node js.

Comment: which of the three members get added? ... how are you adding the three members?

Comment: the first one and the last one. i added them by telegram add member feature. also sometimes INSERT execute twice